# Singleton CoreData manager available to all UINavigationControllers embedded views

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm wondering if the way my CoreData manager interacts with my views is the correct/best/most efficient way possible.

I use a standard singleton pattern, the Apple example, to house my CoreData stack. It also contains utilities for use with a web service and other helper methods.

There's a UINavigation controller with 2 viewControllers, a tableViewController and another viewController programmatically created viewController.

The first two viewControllers are a setup (web service address etc) and login respectively. Right off the bat I pop to the login view (second view). On a successful login, the tableView is pushed. On the selection of a cell, a view is created programmatically and pushed.

Each of these views have a need for the data store, so in their viewDidLoad, I'm grabbing the singleton.

Is this the way to do things? What are other ideas? Can the navigation controller expose properties to all of it's embedded views?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking all three of the questions at the end of your post, or (as I am reading into your question) are you asking the best way to move information from one view controller to another?

Comment: I am asking the last 3 questions. I am able to move information fine, and my current solution works, but this is my first iOS project. Basically, just wondering if my CoreData/view architecture "looks right".

Answer (score 0):

Until recently I used Matt Gallagher's synthesize singleton to do the same thing you mention.

However, recently I converted my project to use ARC, so the singleton setup simplified somewhat. Now I have:

```
static MMPersistentStoreController *sharedMMPersistentStoreController = nil;

+ (MMPersistentStoreController *)sharedMMPersistentStoreController {
    if (sharedMMPersistentStoreController == nil)
    {
        sharedMMPersistentStoreController = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedMMPersistentStoreController; 
 }
```

I think this a pretty standard approach. Certainly it's better than passing the object around everywhere.

As for alternatives, I guess you could `synthesize` it as a `property` of your application delegate then access it via `UIApplication`.

With the former approach, it's a static instance created by the `MMPersistentStoreController` class object. With the latter, the instance is is an `ivar` of an object that will only ever exist once in your application.

Comment: I thought apple dissuaded people from core data singletons ... any reason in particular?

Comment: Reason for what specifically? Thanks